# How are arguments passed to a function through __getattr__

Tags: python, function, inheritance, arguments, getattr

Consider the following code example (python 2.7):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, child):
        self.child = child

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print("Calling __getattr__: "+attr)
        if hasattr(self.child, attr):
            return getattr(self.child, attr)
        else:
            raise AttributeError(attr)

class Child:
    def make_statement(self, age=10):
        print("I am an instance of Child with age "+str(age))

kid = Child()
person = Parent(kid)

kid.make_statement(5)
person.make_statement(20)
```

it can be shown, that the function call `person.make_statement(20)` calls the `Child.make_statement` function through the `Parent`'s `__getattr__` function. In the `__getattr__` function I can print out the attribute, before the corresponding function in the child instance is called. So far so clear.

But how is the argument of the call `person.make_statement(20)` passed through `__getattr__`? How am I able to print out the number '20' in my `__getattr__` function?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are not printing `20` in your `__getattr__` function. The function finds the `make_statement` *attribute* on the Child instance and returns that. As it happens, that attribute is a method, so it is callable. Python thus calls the returned method, and *that* method then prints `20`.

If you were to remove the `()` call, it would still work; we can store the method and call it separately to get `20` printed:

```
>>> person.make_statement
Calling __getattr__: make_statement
<bound method Child.make_statement of <__main__.Child instance at 0x10db5ed88>>
>>> ms = person.make_statement
Calling __getattr__: make_statement
>>> ms()
I am an instance of Child with age 10
```

If you *have* to see the arguments, you'd have to return a wrapper function instead:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    print("Calling __getattr__: "+attr)
    if hasattr(self.child, attr):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print('called with %r and %r' % (args, kw))
            return getattr(self.child, attr)(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    raise AttributeError(attr)
```

This now results in:

```
>>> person.make_statement(20)
Calling __getattr__: make_statement
called with (20,) and {}
I am an instance of Child with age 20
```

Comment: @Alex: Updated, you'd need a wrapper function.

Comment: Yes, from your explanation I had the same idea, but it would have taken me longer for the realization. Thanks a lot, that seem to answer my question.

Comment: One more question though: Does your solution work even within the unittest framework? I see that your solution does not seem to work in such a case and I am trying to nail it down further.

Comment: @Alex: Not sure what you mean. If you want the unittest framework to still detect `test*` methods you need to add a `__dir__` method to list all your proxied method names, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir

Answer (score 0):

For people who found the best answer somewhat confusing like me. I found that `__getattr__` just expects to return callable function which it invokes, and sends the *args and **kwargs.

```
def printf(name, *args, **kwargs):
    print(name)
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)

class MyClass:
    def __getattr__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        # *args and **kwargs are available here as lists and dictionaries, respectively
        # You can use them just like any other argument
        # For example, you can pass them to another function
        return printf

t = MyClass()

t.get("hello", "wow", headers ={"token": "123456789"})
```

Output:

```
hello  
('wow',)
{'headers': {'token': '123456789'}}
```

Which is what I wanted, so you would need to wrap your function with another function to pass *args and *kwargs for that matter.

Comment: The code above does not work, __getattr__ receives has only one arguments : the name of the searched attribute.

Comment: @babebibobu I don't know what you are talking about... It works... I tested it again on an online compiler.

Comment: Sorry, "does not work" was a bit misleading, let me explain :
getattr has only one parameter : the name of the searched attribute.
Your definition :
    def __getattr__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
is misleading : *args and **kwargs are not transmitted and are not available. Hence the need for a wrapper function as in the answer by Martijn Pieters. I hope this makes things clearer.