# Wrapping function calls to xmlrpc server

Tags: python, attributes, xml-rpc

I have a `xmlrpc` server running looking like the following

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

def add(x,y):
    return x+y

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
server.register_function(add, 'add.numbers')
server.serve_forever()
```

which is called used within the following code:

```
import xmlrpclib

class DeviceProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, uri):
        self.rpc = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(uri)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.rpc, attr)

original = DeviceProxy.__getattr__

def mygetattr(device, attr):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        print('called with %r and %r' % (args, kw))
        return original(device, attr)(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper

DeviceProxy.__getattr__ = mygetattr

dev = DeviceProxy("http://localhost:8000/RPC2")
print dev.add.numbers(4,6)
```

As you can see, the `Proxy` class wraps the `xmlrpc` proxy for reasons outside the scope of this question, forwarding arbitrary calls via the `__getattr__` method . For further reasons outside the scope for this question, I need to wrap/replace this `__getattr__` method by a different method to e.g. print out the name of the function called, the arguments etc. (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776504/how-are-arguments-passed-to-a-function-through-getattr)).

But this approach does not work, it gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'numbers'
```

The example works as expected when I

- do not replace `DeviceProxy.__getattr__` with something else
- replace `DeviceProxy.__getattr__` with the function

  def dummy(instance, attr):
      return original(device,attr)
- replace the name of the `xmlrpc` function by a zero-dotted name (e.g. just `sum` instead of `sum.numbers`)

You can verify yourself that the following, direct call via the xmlrpc proxy will work as expected:

```
dev = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000/RPC2")
print dev.add.numbers(4,6)
```

My question: How to solve my problem, i.e. how to be able to wrap/overwrite the `DeviceProxy.__getattr__` correctly to be able to see the function called, all arguments etc WITHOUT making changes in the `xmlrpc` server or the `DeviceProxy` class?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems here:

1. Are all attributes of a DeviceProxy functions? If they're not, then you're sometimes returning a function when an object is expected
2. When you wrap the function, you're not copying across members - use `functools.wraps` to achieve that.

This ought to work

```
from functools import wraps

@wraps(original)  # probably not needed, but sensible
def mygetattr(device, key):
    attr = original(device, key)
    if callable(attr):
        @wraps(attr)  # copy across __name__, __dict__ etc
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            print('called with %r and %r' % (args, kw))
            return attr(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    else:  # handle (or rather, don't) non-callable attributes
        return attr
```

Comment: Your point (1) is a valid point, and I need to have a look at point (2) still. With your code I do not get an error any more, but neither any output! I just get the number `10` printed but not the additional information I was looking for. Maybe I forgot something etc., can post the complete code please?

Comment: When I again do `DeviceProxy.__getattr__ = mygetattr` with your code and execute the test, I get an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 50, in <module>
    print dev.add.numbers(4,6)
  File "code.py", line 22, in mygetattr
    @wraps(attr)  # copy across __name__, __dict__ etc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
TypeError: __name__ must be set to a string object`.

Comment: @Alex: What do you get if you add a `print attr, attr.__name__` just before that?

Comment: Your extra information is not printed because `DeviceProxy.__getattr__` is invoked for `x = dev.add`, but not for `x.numbers`

Comment: So how can I fix this? As you can see, the `xmlrpc` server has some definitions for how functions are called, and they can be `add`, `add.numbers`, `add.numbers.max` or whatever. I do not have any control on the naming within the `xmlrpc` server, but need to print out what exactly has been called.

Comment: If I try to `print attr, attr.__name__` just before the `@wraps(attr)` call I get an  error: xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: '<type \'exceptions.Exception\'>:method "addthem.__str__" is not supported'>